# Scapy bind_layers using a layer condition outside the binding scope

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming, scapy

I'm new to Scapy so maybe this is written down somewhere but I can't find the answer.

I'm trying to create a custom packet dissector but in order to bind specific layers to each other I need to do it on condition of a value in a deeper layer.
I have a minimum of three layers above the RTP layer but the number of 2nd and third layers is determined by a value in the first layer.

Cust1 holds the number of Cust2 layers that will follow. Each Cust2 layer will have a corresponding Cust3 layer to match with it at the end of the chain of Cust2 layers. I've shown an example below where I've used 2a/2b/2c and 3a/3b/3c just to indicate that the numbers are the same layer type but chained together.

**i.e**

If **Cust1** holds a value of **one(1)** then:

UDP / RTP / Cust1 / Cust2a / Cust3a

if **Cust1** holds a value of **two(2)**:

UDP / RTP / Cust1 / Cust2a/Cust2b / Cust3a/Cust3b

if **Cust1** holds a value of **three(3)**:

UDP / RTP / Cust1 / Cust2a/Cust2b/Cust2c / Cust3a/Cust3b/Cust3c

etc...

So how do I reference Cust1 for bindings that are further along in the chain?

```
bind_layers(RTP, Cust1)
bind_layers(Cust1, Cust2a)
bind_layers(Cust2a, Cust2b, {conditional REF_to_Cust1.value})
bind_layers(Cust2b, Cust2c, {conditional REF_to_Cust1.value})
# etc...
```

Please tell me I don't have to create a custom layer for each scenario and use that to get my desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easily possible if you seperate your packet in several layers, it is easily achieveable using some special fields. (You could actually use `guess_payload_class` but it's more of a pain...)

Have a look at [PacketListField](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.fields.html?highlight=PacketListField#scapy.fields.PacketListField) or at the [adequate documentation](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_dissect.html).

This is the general idea:

```py
class Cust2(Packet):
    ...

class Cust3(Packet):
    ...

class Cust1(Packet):
    fields_desc = [
        ByteField("number_of_cust2", 0),
        ...,
        PacketFieldList("cust2s", [], Cust2, count_from=lambda pkt: pkt.number_of_cust2),
        PacketFieldList("cust3s", [], Cust3, count_from=lambda pkt: pkt.number_of_cust2),
    ]
```